# Problem in Iteraiton of a JsonOBJECT: Is impossible to iterate with a while

Tags: java, android, json, rest, loops

I want to iterate in a Json Objet. My Json file is :

```
    [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tagw2": "flemme",
    "conseil2": "travailler"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "tagw": "flemme",
    "conseil": "travailler"
  }
]
```

But my android application always send a empty toast when I try to iterate. I do this with for. This is my code :

```
Button GetData;
GetData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetData);
GetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {   
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    String url = " myserverJsonIPs";
   JsonArrayRequest request=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        String GiveTagw = "";
                        String GiveConseil= "";
                        String testo;
                        try {
                            //JSONObject Info = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject Info = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GiveTagw, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //testo = Info.getString(String.valueOf(id));
                                //GiveTagw = Arrays.asList(Info.getString("tagw").split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                                GiveTagw = Info.getString("tagw");

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GiveTagw , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                GiveConseil = Info.getString("conseil");
                                //testMap4.put(Arrays.asList(Info.getString("tagw").split("\\s*,\\s*")), GiveConseil);
                                //id = id + 1;
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mTextViewResult.setText(GiveTagw);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        mTextViewResult.setText("something wrong");
                    }
                });

                queue.add(request);

            }
        });
```

When I click in the button I created, I don't have "something wrong" error message but only a empty Textview and an empty Toast... I am so confused

When I click to the button the only thing I have in run is :

```
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x6ee583fc90 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x6ee583fc90 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x6ee583fc90 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x6ee583fc90 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x6ee583fc90 disconnect failed
```

The new log run :

```
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tagw
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:560)
W/System.err:     at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:112)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:104)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

LogRun3

```
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=3109
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tagw
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:560)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:112)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:104)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

LOGRUN 3

```
        W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tagw
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:560)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:113)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:105)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=6482
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tagw
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:560)
        at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:113)
W/System.err:     at fr.apprentissage.version2.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:105)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Comment: check if there is an exception or not.

Comment: I edited my post to add the run log, with it I don't do wath to do :(

Comment: print log of exception message in catch block.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how to print this log of exception message? Sorry sometimes I am slow to understand...

Comment: in catch block add line "Log.d("===exce ::  "+e.getMessage());"

Comment: I can't do that for type incompatibility : "Cannot resolve method 'd(java.lang.String)'

Answer (score 0):

You are run toast in background thread, try to move toast in main thread.

```
// read obj1
JSONObject objResult1 = response.getJSONObject(0);
int id1 = objResult1.optInt("id");
String tagw1 = objResult1.optString("tagw2");
String conseil1 = objResult1.optString("conseil2");

// read obj2
JSONObject objResult2 = response.getJSONObject(1);
int id2 = objResult2.optInt("id");
String tagw2 = objResult2.optString("tagw");
String conseil2 = objResult2.optString("conseil");


new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id1:" + id1 + " tagw1:" + tagw1 + " conseil1"  + conseil1  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id2:" + id2 + " tagw2:" + tagw2 + " conseil2"  + conseil2  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```

Comment: I tried to add the Handler you posted in the for loop, but I think this is not what you think I have to do. I have to add this in the main? I can't add it in the main outside the function because GiveTagw is a local variable, i am wrong? Sorry for my difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code may be it will help you.

```
   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    String tagw = "";
    String giveConseil = "";
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject info = response.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = info.getInt("id");
            if (info.has("tagw"))
                tagw = info.getString("tagw");
            if (info.has("tagw2"))
                tagw = info.getString("tagw2");

            if (info.has("conseil"))
                giveConseil = info.getString("conseil");
            if (info.has("conseil2"))
                giveConseil = info.getString("conseil2");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), giveConseil, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I tried to remplace my code by your code. The json server correctly see the "get" request" but my application doesn't print anithing in a toast... I tried to remplace it with a mTextViewResult.setText("test"); but the textview doesn't change and "text" doesn't appear in my app

Comment: try to print in log like this Log.d("TAG",tagw):

Comment: Okay I add the run log with adding Log.d editing my post ("W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for tagw"????)

Comment: i have update my post check again and make sure your json object key is exactly "tagw"

Comment: I have the same log run error I add it editing my post. I copied and remplaced my code by your code after you edited it

Comment: ok do one thing print your response in log like this Log.d("TAG",new Gson().toJson(response)); and send me

Comment: my Android studio programm doesn't recognize your command : cannot find symbol class Gson.

Sorry for all my difficulties I am a new programmer girl

Comment: first add this dependency in your gradle file implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

Comment: Okay I edited my post to present to new logrun. What do you think about it?

Comment: but how it possible some it is tagw2 and sometime is only tagw and your id also int not string

Comment: I edited the LOGRUN 3 for the case of a mistake (but really the only think I did was coping your code and remplacing mine by yours, and in the LOGRUN 3 it is tagw

Comment: can you post me on mail dharmender.manral@gmail.com

Comment: Yes no problem ! I also have discord if you want. Thank you so much for your help !